# How to parse a variable having a dynamic name in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, variables

I do have **variables** like

```
<?php
$num1 = 'txt1';
$num2 = 'txt2';
$num3 = 'txt3';   
...
```

and I do have a **loop**

```
for ($i=1; $i<100; $i++){  
   echo 'This is textNr'.$i.':'   .$num.$i  ;
}
```

I need to produce a result **like:**

This is textNr1: txt1

---

Of course with this code i would get something **like:**

This is textNr1: 'undefined'

---

,because in $num.$i  the $num is not defined;

so $num.$i  should be parsed once and become $num1 and then $num1 should be parsed a second time like:

```
 echo 'This is textNr'.$i.':'   .$num1  ;
```

---

Does anybody know how to handle this? 
Technical term of this problem is "variable variables" or "dynamic variables"!

Comment: Why not just use an array and loop that?

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to do inside the loop.

Comment: @Lance he thought using `$num.$i` can get `$num1` if `$i=1`

Comment: He's trying to loop the variables with `$i` like `$num.$i == $num1` etc. But this is the wrong approach...

Comment: Ohhh. I see. Well, for starters define $num inside the loop.

Comment: Thx I got it, I will use arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an array (Antoine's answer) is better practice. But if you want/need to use your solution

```
for ($i=1; $i<100; $i++){  
   echo 'This is textNr'.$i.':' . ${"num$i"}  ;
}
```

PHP does first evaluate `"num$i"` and use that result to find a variable with that name,
 thanks to `${ }`.

For more about this, see: [PHP-Manual (Variable Variables)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Note that you can use a deeper level of variable names

```
$a = "b";
$b = "c";
${${$a}}  = 7; 
echo $c; // echoes 7
```

Via an array: you could also declare an array

```
$array = ('text1', 'text2', 'text3', ... , 'textN');
echo count ( $array ); // echoes N, size of array
```

To display its items

```
// Loop on array
foreach ($array as $text) {
  echo "$text\n";
}
```

displays *text1*, *text2*, ... *textN*  (one per line)

You could also use a *for* loop

```
$n = count($array);
for($i=0 ; $i<$n ; $i++) echo $array[$i] . "\n";
```

that produces the same output.

Answer (score 4):

You should do something like:

```
  $nums = array();
  $nums[0] = 'txt1';
  $nums[1] = 'txt2';

  for ($i=0; $i<100; $i++){  
    echo 'This is textNr'.$i.':'   .$nums[$i]  ;
  }
```

Or start the index at 1 in the array, if you want to start it at one in the loop,

Comment: Array seems to be the magic here. Thx, this should work.  I'm quite new to PHP, but I guess arrays are often quite handy.

Answer (score 2):

php variable can be constructed with curly brackets like example below:

```
echo 'This is textNr'.$i.':'   .${'num'.$i}  . "\r\n" ;
```

you can put anything that returnrs string between brackets

Answer (score 1):

The php term you look for is "variable variable". php its one of very few languages that support it, and for a good reason - the approach smells wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
$nums = array();
  $nums[0] = 'txt1';
  $nums[1] = 'txt2';

  for ($i=0; $i<count($nums); $i++){  
    echo 'This is textNr'.$i.':'   .$nums[$i]  ;
  }
?>
```

Is an improved version of the answer you have choosed. It will only show the values you have set to the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array , like this:

```
$nums = array('txt1','txt2','txt3');

for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($nums); $i++){  
    echo 'This is textNr'.$i.':'   .$nums[$i]  ;
}
```

The upper bound of array should be the size of the array, otherwise you may get empty values at $nums[x]

Comment: thx for the **sizeof($nums)** this comes quite handy , know this from javascript as array.length